# How do role and actor bonuses interact?

Tags: chroma-squad

I've started my first sentai studio!  Now I have to choose my actors, and their roles.  My problem: I don't know how to intelligently select my roles!  For example, the Lead role provides a 50% Health buff.  But my very first actor has a 20% Health penalty.  Does this mean I only get a 30% Health buff?  Or is it multiplicative, so it would be 120% of Health?

Answer (score 6):

Dev here:
it would be 50% - 20% = 30% of extra health. We sum up every modifier before applying.

Cheers!